# Excel - counting my available inventory with Excel formula

Tags: excel

I have an inventory list as follows:

```
              Revenue  Count
Blue Shirt(S)     $10      0    
Blue Shirt(M)     $10      0     
Blue Shirt(M)      0       1     
Blue Shirt(M)      0       1     
Blue Shirt(M)      0       1
```

If I sell an item, I input the revenue, and the amount in the "count" column adjusts to 0, noting that I have sold that specific item and it is no longer in stock. The 1 in the "count" column represents what I have available in stock. I am trying to find a formula which will automatically update the amount of Blue Shirt (M) I have available in stock, which would be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first column is A

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,"Blue Shirt(M)",$C$2:$C$6)
```

You can replace the "Blue Shirt(M)" with a cell that has that text and then the number will change when you change the text in the cell so if you change it to "Blue Shirt(S)" it will return 0